# Could not find org.koin:koin-core:2.2.2

Tags: android, koin, jcenter, maven-central

I have recently removed `jcenter()` repository from the project-level build Gradle.

Since then Koin (version: 2.2.2) started giving me the compile-time error below:

`Could not find org.koin:koin-core:2.2.2`

Answer (score 17):

Adding `mavenCentral` repository instead of `jcenter` and updating the version of Koin to `3.0.1` solved the issue.

Do not forget to update the dependencies from `org.koin` to `io.insert-koin` as well.

https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin#maven-central

Comment: Or just change the group id to `io.insert-koin` to keep using 2.2.2 from mavenCentral.

Comment: The package name does not change @Vikash. Updating dependency in your app level build.gradle should be enough or in respective modules.

Answer (score 11):

Now use `implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.0.1"` and remove `jcenter` from project build.gradle

Comment: this the exact thing I'm using